# XCode undefined symbols error with c++ dynamic library

Tags: c++, xcode, dynamic-library

I am trying to create C++ dynamic library in XCode 6,  very simple one just as a test.
I've built it and trid to integrate it to both c++ other app and Obj-C app, but I always get same error !
I've searched everywhere ! I'm loosing my mind ;p

See codes of my library, of my test code and error message below :

**Library iOSLibView.cpp :**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "iOSLibView.h"


    iOSLibView::iOSLibView(){

    }

    iOSLibView::~iOSLibView(){

    }

void iOSLibView::testLib(){
    std::cout << "First C++ Lib" << std::endl;
}
```

**Library iOSLibView.h :**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

class iOSLibView{
    public :
    iOSLibView();
        ~iOSLibView();

        void testLib();
};
```

Here's the code in second project which integrates my compiled dynamic library :

**Test code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "iOSLibView.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    iOSLibView libTest;
    //libTest.testLib();

    return 0;
}
```

**And error message :**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "iOSLibView::iOSLibView()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "iOSLibView::~iOSLibView()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In second project, I added .dyn file in build phase, **Link binary with libraries** and **copy files**.

I tried too to build my library as a static one and everything works perfectly ! I just meet issues with dynamic libraries...

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Eww `#include "iOSLibView.cpp"`

Comment: For #include "iOSLibView.cpp", copy mistake, sorry.... I've corrected above code.